# Why mysqli_fetch_all() is undefined in my live server?

Tags: php, mysqli, server

I am trying to fetch all the rows in a table. When I used `mysqli_fetch_all()` function in my wamp server, this is working fine. But when using in a live server this function is called as undefined function.

I can fetch the single row data using the `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` function.

```
$connection = mysqli_connect( 'localhost', 'root', '', 'students');

if( !$connection ) {
    echo 'Database establshin error ' . mysqli_connect_error().' And the error number is ' . mysqli_connect_errno();
}

$query = mysqli_query( $connection, "SELECT * FROM studentinfomation");
$results = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $query );

echo $results['studentName']; // THis is working fine..
```

But when I am using `mysqli_fetch_all()` function it is not working:

```
$query= mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM studentinfomation");
$results = mysqli_fetch_all( $query, MYSQLI_ASSOC ); // This works in wamp server

foreach( $results  as $result ) {
  echo $result['studentName'];
}
```

This codes are not working in my live server.

Comment: A link is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/25355124/3568847

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php
this function is available since PHP 5.3
Maybe PHP server version is older.